# Inserting into SQL with pyodbc from remote computer

Tags: python, pyodbc

Hello I am using my second computer to gather some data and insert it into the SQL database. I set up everything when it comes to reading and writing the database remotely, and I can insert new rows just by using the normal SQL.

With pyodbc I can read tables, but when I insert new data, nothing happens. No error message, but also no new rows in the table.

I wonder if anyone has faced this issue before and knows what the solution is.

Comment: *"when I insert new data, nothing happens"* - Did you remember to `.commit()` the changes?

Answer (score 0):

The `cursor.execute()` method only prepares the SQL statement. Then, since this is an `INSERT` statement, you must use the `cursor.commit()` method for the records to actually populate your table. Likewise for a `DELETE` statement, you need to `commit`, as well.

Without more perspective here, I can only assume that you are not committing the insert.

Notice, similarly, that when you run `cursor.execute("""select * from yourTable""")`, you need to run `cursor.fetchall()` or another fetch statement to actually retrieve and view your query.